# How to see apple watch home screen into simulator?

Tags: ios-simulator, apple-watch

Is there a way to see apple watch appliactions in simulator with icons same as iPhone? How we are tapping application icon in iPhone simulator same thing i want to do it in apple watch simulator. As of now i am just running my watch application into simulator want to see apple watch icon as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The WatchKit simulator doesn't support viewing anything other than your own app at this time.

Comment: As iam working on business application the behavior is first only i should show the login screen once user got logged in should show the direct application screen only. Like this scenarios we can't able to test it in simulator.